# Getting all movies belonging to a set of tags

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

So I have a Neo4J db of movies along with their genres. I'd like to find all movies that belong to all of the genres in a set.

```
EG:

Matrix - Sci-fi, Thriller, Action
Harry Potter - Drama, Fiction, Thriller
Pulp Fiction - Drama, Thriller
```

Now, what I want is movies belonging to Drama, as well as Thriller. 
This means Harry, and Pulp, but not Matrix, even though it also belongs to Thriller.

Any ideas on the query?

Comment: Are the genres nodes unto themselves or properties on the movie nodes?

Comment: @DaveBennett Genre nodes are separate labels, with their own properties. They are joined to Movies via a "contains" relationship, and movies are related to genres by a "genre" relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `MATCH` your `Movie` nodes and filter on the relationships two `Genre` nodes:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE (m)-[:GENRE]->(:Genre {genre_name: 'Drama'})
AND (m)-[:GENRE]->(:Genre {genre_name: 'Thriller'})
RETURN m
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need a relationship in each direction (`contains` and `genres`), as you mentioned in a comment. Just one direction is good enough, since you can easily traverse a relationship in either direction. In this answer, I will just use the `genre` relationship.
2. I assume that you first create an index on the `name` property of the `Genre` node.

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON :Genre(name);
   ```

   This index will allow the actual query, below, to quickly get the desired `Genre` nodes without having to iterate through every such node.

   ```
   MATCH (g1:Genre { name: 'Drama' })<-[:genre]-(m:Movie)-[:genre]->(g2:Genre { name: 'Thriller' })
   USING INDEX g1:Genre(name)
   USING INDEX g2:Genre(name)
   RETURN m;
   ```

   This simple and efficient query forces (via `USING INDEX`) the Cypher planner to use the above index for both `Genre` nodes (since the planner currently only does that automatically for one of them).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following data set:

```
Create (g1:Genre {name: 'Sci-fi' } )
Create (g2:Genre {name: 'Thriller' } )
Create (g3:Genre {name: 'Action' } )
Create (g4:Genre {name: 'Drama' } )
Create (g5:Genre {name: 'Fiction' } )
Create (m1:Movie {name: 'Matrix' } )
Create (m1)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g1)
Create (m1)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g2)
Create (m1)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g3)
Create (m2:Movie {name: 'Harry Potter' } )
Create (m2)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g4)
Create (m2)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g5)
Create (m2)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g2)
Create (m3:Movie {name: 'Pulp Fiction' } )
Create (m3)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g4)
Create (m3)-[:IS_GENRE]->(g2)
```

If you use the following query you can only match genres in a particular list but then only return results where the number of genres per movie is the same size as your list.

```
with ['Thriller','Drama'] as genre_list
match (m:Movie)-[r:IS_GENRE]->(g:Genre)
using index g:Genre(name)
where g.name in genre_list
with genre_list,m.name as movie, collect(g.name) as genres
where size(genres) = size(genre_list)
return movie, genres
```

I think this is pretty interesting if you only have two genres that you are matching on...

```
match p=allShortestPaths((g1:Genre {name: 'Thriller'} )-[:IS_GENRE*..2]-(g2:Genre {name: 'Drama'} ))
using index g1:Genre(name)
using index g2:Genre(name)
return (nodes(p)[1]).name as movie, [(nodes(p)[0]).name, (nodes(p)[2]).name] as genres
```

Comment: your approach doesn't seem to be working. I am getting results where the  movie has only one matching genre.

Comment: I spent a little time looking at it to determine how you would get those results.  The only thing I could come up with is that perhaps you have some `Movie` nodes that are matched to the same `Genre` more than once.  You could use this query to identify if you have Movies linked to the same Genre more than once. `match (m:Movie)-[r]->(n:Genre)
with m.name as movie, collect(id(r)) as ids, n.name as genre, count(*) as count
order by count(*) desc
where count > 1
return *`.  The first query will easily allow you to change the number of genres you want to match.